# How to properly format the text coming from my backend in reactjs so that some parts of the text takes up new line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is exactly how my code looks and it's coming from the backend dispalying as text . The isssue is that some of the text are numbered and I want to display that part that is numbered in anew line so the text is properly formatted on the ui

```
{webSocketMessages &&
    webSocketMessages.map((message, index) => {
      let parsedMessage =
        typeof message === 'string' ? JSON.parse(message) : message
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <span>{parsedMessage.text.author}:</span> <br />
          <p>{parsedMessage.text.message}</p>
        </div>
      )
    })}
</div>
```